# Blurred tikz picture (Hermite-Gaussian modes)

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I want to draw Hermite-Gaussian modes using tikz, all that is really needed is a blurred circle and blurred lines that overlay splitting it into different sections as shown in this picture:
[image]

I am not even able to find a proper way of doing the first one, since all blurring options i have found so far are not smooth enough.

Comment: The first one is relatively simple. You can draw it with: `\node[circle, inner color=white, outer color=black, inner sep= 0.5 cm, label={[color=white]below:00}] (00) {};`, on a black background. The others however are complicated. I've tried with a blurred line in between, but the results are not very good.

Comment: I am using \fill with a fading option.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

With functional shading one has full control of the output --- as long as one knows the correct math formula.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}    
\pgfdeclarefunctionalshading{Hermite-Gaussian modes}{\pgfpoint{-25bp}{-25bp}}{\pgfpoint{25bp}{25bp}}{}{
    10 atan sin 1000 mul cos 1 add
    exch
    10 atan sin 1000 mul cos 1 add
    mul 4 div
    dup dup
}
\begin{document}
    \tikz\path[shading=Hermite-Gaussian modes](-10,-10)rectangle(10,10);
\end{document}
```

[image]

## Explanation

One may also check Ti*k*Z's manual **109.2.3 General (Functional) Shadings** and PDF's standard **8.7.4.5.2 Type 1 (Function-Based) Shadings** and **Annex B Operators in Type 4 Functions**.

### Some technical comment:

The canvas is 50bp by 50bp. The range of coordinate is from (-25bp, -25bp) to (25bp, 25bp), that is, the input is two real numbers falling between -25 to 25. The output of your function should be a triple of numbers between 0 and 1, black is (0,0,0), red is (1,0,0), white is (1,1,1).

I suggest that one should test the PDF file by the *official* renderer. By *official* I mean Adobe Acrobat Reader DC, which used to be called Adobe Reader. It happens that *unofficial* PDF readers tends to disable some insecure features of PDF, and sometimes functional shading is one of them.

Go back to my code, it is simply a function:

[image]

where

[image]

is a function looks like *z* when *z* is small and is constant when *z* is large.

I added two `dup` in my code so that when it finishes calculating the gray scale, it will then duplicate the result so R, G, B channels will get the same result. (In some rare case, if your function output just one real number, the PDF renderer will treat it like it is the gray scale. For stability and portability, however, I should have `dup` the result.)

Comment: Wow! im amazed by how compact your code is. I have no idea how you definition actually works, in other words, i am not able to draw the other modes. Would you be so kind to quickly add some comments on how you approached this and what some of the terms mean?

Comment: Also my output does not match yours. It is blue and the resolution is very low.

Comment: @Josh I added some references and fixed my code. Now Adobe Acrobat Reader DC will give you the correct result.

Comment: @ Symbol1 alright, it works! One thanks you. The PDF reader was indeed the issue here. However i do not understand how the picture is produced with such a huge frequency on the cos. If i plot your function from [-25,25] (for x and y) and use 17 instead of 1000 i get the function i would expect, but then pgf does not do what i expect.

Comment: @Josh The input of trigonometric functions in given in degrees! So 1000° ≈ 17.44 rad, everything is good!

Comment: @Simboly1 oh i should have known. Last question: if i want to draw the "even" modes i just need to flip the sign of the cos() function, which with my reduced knowledge of this stack language would be:

10 atan sin 1000 mul cos neg 1 add

exch

10 atan sin 1000 mul cos neg 1 add

mul 4 div

dup dup

or alternatively -1 mul. Both only seem to work if i then divide by 3 instead 4, which does not really makes sence. I think i don't really understand the stacking, so my question in short is: how do i invert the cos() sign?

Comment: @Josh If you need, say, only four crests, then you might need to reduce the frequency. Something like `10 atan sin 800 mul cos neg 1 add exch 10 atan sin 800 mul cos neg 1 add mul 3 div dup dup` would work.

Answer (score 4):

After reading the tikz and pgf manual i have produced this:
[image]

I don't quite like it, its okey but they could look better. I would really appreciate some tips. Maybe the only way is really plotting the 2 dimentional Hermite-Gauss intensity distributions. Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}


\tikzfading[name=fade out,
inner color=transparent!0,
outer color=transparent!100]

\tikzfading[name=middle,
top color=transparent!100,
bottom color=transparent!100,
middle color=transparent!0]

\tikzfading[name=middle rot,
right color=transparent!100,
left color=transparent!100,
middle color=transparent!0]

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[black] (0,0) rectangle (6,6);

\fill[white!99!black,path fading=fade out] (2,4) circle (1cm);

\fill[white!99!black,path fading=fade out] (2,2) circle (1cm);

\fill[white!0!black,path fading=middle] (0,1.8) rectangle +(4,0.4);


\fill[white!99!black,path fading=fade out] (4,4) circle (1cm);

\fill[white!0!black,path fading=middle] (3,3.8) rectangle +(2,0.4);
\fill[white!0!black,path fading=middle rot] (3.8,3) rectangle +(0.4,2);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

After playing around with `pgfplots` I have found a "simple" solution. It takes quite a while to compile, however the results and the easy input make up for it:
[image]

Here is the MWE along with the actual 3D plots:
[image]

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{myaxis/.style={%
        view={0}{90}, 
        % view={60}{60}, % enable for 3D view
        samples=50,
        hide axis,
        colormap={bw}{gray(0cm)=(0); gray(0.1cm)=(0.15) ; gray(1cm)=(1)},
        width=8cm,
        height=8cm}}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.5}


\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[myaxis]
\addplot3[surf,shader=interp,domain=-20:20] {(exp(-x^2/100))^2*(exp(-y^2/100))^2};
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[xshift=6cm,myaxis]
\addplot3[surf,shader=interp,domain=-20:20] {(0.28*x*exp(-x^2/100))^2*(exp(-y^2/100))^2};
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[yshift=-6cm,myaxis]
\addplot3[surf,shader=interp,domain=-20:20] {(exp(-x^2/100))^2*(0.28*y*exp(-y^2/100))^2};
\end{axis}


\begin{axis}[myaxis,xshift=6cm,yshift=-6cm]
\addplot3[surf,shader=interp,domain=-20:20] {(0.28*x*exp(-x^2/100))^2*(0.28*y*exp(-y^2/100))^2};
\end{axis}


\begin{axis}[myaxis,xshift=12cm]
\addplot3[surf,shader=interp,domain=-22:22] {(-2 + 0.0784*x^2)*exp(-x^2/100))^2*(exp(-y^2/100))^2};
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[myaxis,yshift=-12cm]
\addplot3[surf,shader=interp,domain=-22:22] {exp(-x^2/100))^2*((-2 + 0.0784*y^2)*exp(-y^2/100))^2};
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[myaxis,xshift=12cm,yshift=-6cm]
\addplot3[surf,shader=interp,domain=-22:22] {((-2 + 0.0784*x^2)*exp(-x^2/100))^2*(0.28*y*exp(-y^2/100))^2};
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[myaxis,xshift=6cm,yshift=-12cm]
\addplot3[surf,shader=interp,domain=-22:22] {((0.28*x)*exp(-x^2/100))^2*((-2 + 0.0784*y^2)*exp(-y^2/100))^2};
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[myaxis,xshift=12cm,yshift=-12cm]
\addplot3[surf,shader=interp,domain=-22:22] {((-2 + 0.0784*x^2)*exp(-x^2/100))^2*((-2 + 0.0784*y^2)*exp(-y^2/100))^2};
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

If anyone is interested in plotting higher modes than the ones provided here you just need higher order Hermite polynomials, which can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials).