# Plotting Laguerre Gaussian beam intensity in transverse and line profile via center?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Hi can someone please help me with Laguerre Gaussian beam(looks like a doughnut or vortex)?

[image]

Comment: Like this https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/333330/blurred-tikz-picture-hermite-gaussian-modes ?

Comment: The equation is very complex to plot. I am not sure if such functions are available on latex. It is called Laguerre polynomial.

Comment: [Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/82425/121799) are additional possibilities. No, Laguerre polynomials are not too complex to be plotted, but this is a LaTeX site, so if you provide equations and an example, people will be happy to help you, but they are less eager to dig out from the internet and guess what you might want.

Answer (score 16):

Here is an attempt to draw the most complicated one I saw on google image.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}    
\pgfdeclarefunctionalshading{Laguerre-Gaussian modes}{\pgfpoint{-25bp}{-25bp}}{\pgfpoint{25bp}{25bp}}{}{
                % x y
    2 copy      % x y x y
    exch atan   % x y theta
    4 mul       % x y 4theta
    cos         % x y cos(4theta)
    dup mul     % x y cos^2(4theta)
    3 1 roll    % cos^2(4theta) x y
    dup mul exch dup mul
    add sqrt    % cos^2(4theta) r
    20 mul      % cos^2(4theta) 20r
    90 add      % cos^2(4theta) 20r+90
    cos dup mul % cos^2(4theta) cos(20r+90)
    mul         % cos^2(4theta)*cos(20r+90)
    sqrt
}
\begin{document}
    \tikz\path[shading=Laguerre-Gaussian modes](-10,-10)rectangle(10,10);
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I would give +100 if I could. Do you *know* the postscript syntax, or do you use a tool to convert human readable instructions into this language?

Comment: @marmot The shading accepts a very restricted subset of postscript. See `PDF32000_2008.pdf` Appendix B. I have some muscle memory inherited from the last time I answered the Hermite-Gaussian question.

Comment: You can tell that it is not from an automatic tool because `cos(20r+90)` should be `cos^2(20r+90)`

Comment: @marmot You can give +100 : [start a bounty](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/bounty) after 2 days.

Comment: @marmot you said "I would give +100 if I could". Come on! You have zillions of points to give ;)

Comment: @Kpym Yes, but 111,111 reads better than 111,061.

Comment: I have a screen shot with 25555 points.